# Setting msExchMailboxGuid for AD

Tags: php, ldap, exchange-server-2010

I'm trying to create an Exchange 2010 mailbox using php. I've read [a thread](https://sourceforge.net/p/adldap/discussion/358759/thread/bea0158a/) that mentions `msExchMailboxGuid` is required to create the mailbox. I'm using [adLDAP](https://sourceforge.net/p/adldap/) as a wrapper around the ldap functionality.

I'm generating a guid fine, I just can't figure out how to send it so AD likes it. I am sending it the same way the format should be to search using a guid as a hex string, which I can do without a problem.

When attempting to set that attribute, I get a `Constraint violation` for that field, which from searching seems to be a length issue.

Here's my guid:

`66caeefb-dfc0-4f30-8d83-6b4d4d6198cf`

Here it is in UTF-8 hex:

`\fb\ee\ca\66\c0\df\30\4f\8d\83\6b\4d\4d\61\98\cf`

I've tried it as unencoded, with slashes, without slashes, with slashes escaped, plain string guid, plain string guid without dashes... How can I send it so it will be accepted?

If I don't include `msExchMailboxGuid`, the AD account gets created successfully but no mailbox exists.

Comment: I've found this( https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/04bc7c24-c43d-42e8-9cf7-f5a444dc65fd/creating-exchange-2013-mailbox-with-ldap?forum=winserverManagement), which implies that if you populate `mailNickname` the `msExchMailboxGuid` should be automatically created *( on Exchange versions 2010 and 2013, specifically )*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active Directory is expecting `msExchMailboxGuid` to be a binary value when creating/modifying users. You were on the right track with the hex value. Take the hex without slashes and pass it to hex2bin:

```
$mailboxGuid = hex2bin('fbeeca66c0df304f8d836b4d4d6198cf');
```

However, you'll probably run into more issues than just the GUID. If you're willing to use a separate library, it's possible to create Exchange Mailboxes (Exchange 2010 - 2016) using the LdapTools library:

https://github.com/ldaptools/ldaptools/blob/master/docs/en/cookbook/Creating-Exchange-Mailboxes.md

I would suggest the newer AdLdap2 library, but I don't think it supports Exchange stuff anymore natively in the library.

Comment: I actually made the switch to LdapTools and had success. I learned that you shouldn't have to set the guid, but some other properties. After that it worked like a charm with LdapTools. Thanks for the answer. Working with AD is very new to me!